# How to Access elements in Bootstrap Drop down in Single Page (When Multiple Bootstrap in single page)

Tags: selenium

During Run time, A web page contains 4 Bootstrap drop down when i try to access particular bootstrap drop down it is clicked, but unable to select/access the elements from Drop down.

I tried "for" loop, still i am unable to access the element.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwlWM.png

Post Expansion:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMAi6.png

Please let me know if you need further details.

Thanks,
Bala

Comment: Could you please share the html instead of snapshot.

Comment: Post the code you tried and the results. It should just be click the dropdown to open it and then click one of the exposed elements. You might need a brief pause after the first click to let the dropdown open depending on how large, etc. it is.